# Removing _dc parameter in Ext

Tags: extjs

Using [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29), default [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) add to GET-request `_dc` parameter. For example

```
GET /ConnViewProcessing/?_dc=1263286227619
```

How to remove this parameter?

PS: it's necessary to manually cache response to `ETag` and `If-None-Match`.

Comment: for Ext-JS 6 those 3 methods dont work...
the only thing i found was to put in the boot.js disableCaching: true,
i know it makes no sense, but if you look at the code in boot.js, that's how it works.
anyway, it doesn't really help, because then some of the callbacks are not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set `disableCaching` option to false:

```
Ext.Ajax.disableCaching = false;
```

Comment: This looks like a global flag.  Is there a way to do this per request?  I have some requests that I want to cache and some I want the cache-busting parameter added to.

Comment: One a side note - Disable caching will lead to cached data in IE (and maybe others).

Comment: Where do you actually put this value?

Answer (score 22):

Using Ext JS 4.1, and after adding the following code to `app.js`, the `_dc` parameter disappears:

```
// Disable _dc parameter

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    disableCaching: false
});

// My App

Ext.application({
```

Comment: This only affects the loading of resources, not Ext.Ajax. In case others come across this answer and want to be able to disable cache busting for scripts etc when using Architect, or just want to disable it only when debugging I have posted an answer that provides more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992255/857209)

Answer (score 17):

The proper way to accomplish that with Sencha Cmd 6.x is to set a (global) switch in `app.json` (because all of those hacks and overrides might interfere unnecessarily with the functionality):

```
"loader": {
    "cache": true
},
```

Then run `sencha app refresh`, in order to update the application's `bootstrap.json`.

Alternatively,  one can configure `Ext.Loader` (at run-time):

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching: false});
```

When scrolling upwards and reading the actual question, concerning `Ext.Ajax` (per request):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({url: '/ConnViewProcessing', disableCaching: false});
```

The result: no more _dc parameters on scripted requests.

@see [Sencha Cmd 6.x - The Microloader](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/microloader.html).

Comment: I had to do it this way after upgrading from Sencha Architect v2.2 to v3.2. It seems tha tthe run-time loader setting no longer seems to work, presumably because Architect now uses SenchaCmd.

Comment: I just discovered that I can disable the use of SenchaCmd by Architect 3.2 by disabling **Build Tools** in **Project Settings** -> **Framework** which means I can again use `disableCaching=false` in the loader settings, and even change it at runtime as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992255/857209)

Answer (score 10):

Note that the use of Ext.Loader has changed in ExtJS 5.

In ExtJS 5, caching can be disabled:

- temporarily by adding "`?cache`" to the end of the URL
- by setting a cookie called 'ext-cache' with the value of 1
- or by editing the file `.sencha/app/Boot.js` and setting the `'_config.disableCaching`' property to be true (overwriting the dynamic lookup).

Answer (score 8):

I am using ExtJS 4.2, but this should work for Ext JS 4.1 and on.  In the proxy there is a property called noCache you should set this to false.

```
Ext4.define('Server',{
    extend: 'Ext4.data.Model',
    fields: [
            {name: 'id'},
            {name: 'key'},
            {name: 'value'}
    ],
    proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'yaddayaddayadda',
            noCache: false,
            reader : {
                    type: 'json'
            }

    }
});
```

The reason my code says Ext4.  is because I am using the sandbox mode as I move old Ext JS 3x code into 4.2

Comment: Confirm that noCache works for Ajax Proxy under v4.2.1 (double negation sucks)

Comment: Can confirm that this approach still works with Ext JS 6.6.0.  If you're looking to disable the "don't cache" param on a Ajax requests to particular service(s) this method allows for that

Answer (score 7):

This should work with extjs 4.0.7:

```
Ext.Loader.config.disableCaching = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the flag `disableCaching` to `false` (double negation - yay!) on the [Ext.data.Connection](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) should do the trick.

For more, look at the [disableCaching](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-cfg-disableCaching)-documentation.

(Please note that quite a few classes in Ext seem to have the option available, so you might have to muck around a bit.)

Answer (score 2):

For those that want to set "disableCaching: false" in Sencha Architect 3+, here is how..:

1. In the project inspector window, select the top node,
   "Application"
2. Then in the "Config" window below that where you
   set the object properties, etc, select "Loader Config"..  in my case
   I had to click the "+" to the right of this as I hadn't set any
   items yet.  This will create a new "LoaderXX" object in the "Project
   Inspector" window above; Loader25 in my case.
3. Now either select the new object in the
   "Project Inspector" window, or click on the right arrow beside the
   new "LoaderXX" (Loader25 in my case).  This will take you to the
   properties for the object.
4. Untick the "disableCaching" item.

Save the project and refresh the browser window, and enjoy persistent breakpoints, etc, etc in Chrome.

Comment: Works as you described !

Comment: Didn't work for me with Architect v3.2. I didn't try earlier 3.x versions. The code is changed to set `disableCaching: false` but I suspect that this run-time loader setting no longer works because Architect now uses SenchaCmd when saving the project. Modifying the **app.json** file as per syslogic's answer did work however.

Comment: Sorry @GlennLawrence, Early 2014 thankfully was the last time I set eyes on Sencha Architect and Sencha Touch.  :-)  I think it was more the dodgy code that I inherited that made life so bad, or maybe it was the client.  Either way, I'm not sad to see the back end of that project.

Comment: No worries @Ads. I just discovered that I can disable the use of SenchaCmd by Architect 3.2 by disabling **Build Tools** in **Project Settings** -> **Framework** which means that your answer is still valid. I figured out a way you can can even change it at runtime as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992255/857209)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to disable _dc in ExtJS 4.2.x globally on my project:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.Connection', {override:'Ext.data.Connection', disableCaching:false });
Ext.define('Ext.data.proxy.Server', {override:'Ext.data.proxy.Server', noCache:false });
Ext.define('Ext.data.JsonP', {override:'Ext.data.JsonP', disableCaching:false });
```

This is ugly, but any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: url,
    disableCaching:false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided that I wanted the cache to be destroyed client side, but server side I was using my own caching mechanism (PHP's APC).

I left the _dc in the Ext ajax request, but then removed it from the REQUEST_URI, and then use the REQUEST_URI as the basis for the cache key

I found this useful: [Regular expression to remove one parameter from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842681/regular-expression-to-remove-one-parameter-from-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you develop under Sencha CMD you can do like this

```
http://localhost:1841/?disableCacheBuster
```

or just

```
http://localhost:1841/?cache
```

Answer (score 0):

For all who are looking for a way to disable it in a newer version:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    noCace: false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Ext.NET on top of Ext.JS. It adds some more voodoo to Ext.js...
I tried to get rid of the dc= parameter, but all mentioned configurations did not work. So, this is my uber-effective, uber-dirty solution:

```
Ext.Date.now = function () { return ""; }
```

As far as I can see, Ext.Date.now() is only used for the caching logic. So it should be relativity save.