# How to match a number in an url value pair

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a Javascript function. I need to grab the number 228 from the following variable

```
var cancelURL = "artGallery.cgi?productid=228&key=photo&resultsC=20";
```

Can someone show me how to write the regex pattern to search for a number in a value pair?

Comment: is it always going to be `productid=<some number>` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842681/regular-expression-to-remove-one-parameter-from-query-string

Comment: Yes Xander, always a different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = (cancelURL.match(/(?:\?|&)productid=(\d+)/) || [null,null])[1];

alert(n);
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion considering there might be another variable like **mproductid** or if there's a chance that the value might be empty: `var s = (cancelURL.match(/(\?|&)productid=(\d*)/) || ['','',''])[2];`

Comment: should've been **n = etc.** instead of `s = etc.` sorry for that.

Comment: @inhan: Good idea. Updated. Only change I made was to make the group a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always looking for the `productid`, you can use `/productid=([^&]*)/i` as your regex. That will grab everything after the `=` and before the next `&`.

Comment: The previous answer worked for me, I really appreciate your comment and will make sure to test it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regexp to match the whole url, and then within the matched content look for groups named `par` and `value`, which matches the parameter and the corresponding value after `=` respectively:

```
[^?]+\?(\&?(?<par>\w+)=(?<value>\w+))+
```

This is a general solution, but solves the specific problem of looking for a `productid` parameter also.

Comment: I will test it too. Thank You Sina.