# Remove Single Query String from URL Using Reg Ex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've read [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842681/regular-expression-to-remove-one-parameter-from-query-string) pages supplying the RegEx, but the post doesn't seem to be working in my tests.  I'm just wanting to remove the `page=X` portion from a url string (`/search?page=2&some_var=foo`).

When I try this:

```
urlStr = req.url
urlStr.replace(/&foo(=[^&]*)?|^foo(=[^&]*)?&?/, '')
```

It doesn't remove the page portion.  If I move the page to the end or middle of the string the RegEx elector works.

Anyone have a better Reg Ex solution?  I'm only going to have a few query strings so I'm pretty sure I'm not going to run into edge cases.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bobp5OHVsWY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
urlStr = urlStr.replace(/\bpage=[^&]+/, '');
```

Comment: You know what's funny?  The reason I ran into this was because I failed to actually replace urlStr (I just did urlstr.replace()).  Haha!

Comment: Perhaps `/\bpage.../` to prevent false matches (e.g. `'multipage=false'`)

Comment: Basically I just did urlStr.replace(blah blah), not urlStr = urlStr.replace().  Gotta love putting your foot in your mouth!